# UILabel Slot Machine Progressive Animation

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, animation

I would like to have a label that displays a number animate like seen in the video below. When the number changes, then the animation starts. How can I accomplish this? Is there anything on Cocoa Controls? Couldn't find anything. By the way, I'm better at coding things, not really on the design/graphics/animations side of things.

The label animation is at 1:17. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MthxLr6sobU

```
    CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
    animation.duration = 1.0;
    animation.type = kCATransitionMoveIn;
    animation.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop;
    animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    [progressiveLabel.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"changeTextTransition"];

    progressiveLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%@", [dataSplit objectAtIndex:1]];
```

Comment: you could have tried something first

Comment: I did, but the way it worked was that a fade would happen and the number would change all at once instead of increasing like that video.

Comment: why didnt you posted your code ?

Comment: @Valerij What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need use two UILabel and move it with animation. I tried to portray on the image that you need to do.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/1eeyp7wz8esgrso/Untitled-1.png